# Nav Bar has added padding which is not in my CSS code

Tags: css, html-lists, navigationbar

[in the "ul" Elememt it shows that it has padding on the left side (padding is green and the orange is margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zxAj.png)

but when I looked through what I've got in my CSS structure i do not not have any padding at all

[My Nav Bar elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2NFa.png)

I tried to fix it by checking through the dev tools but nothing happened and then I tried removing some properties in my CSS but it didn't make any changes

Comment: Please read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question - for starters, images of code are impossible to debug.  Instead, [edit] your question and include a [mre] for faster troubleshooting

Comment: What CSS do you see being applied when you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility?

Comment: It's almost certainly your browser adding default padding for the ul element - you should  be able to see this on the inspect (I've just seen it on Chrome setting padd-inline-start to 40px)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists 

_"The <ul> and <ol> elements have a top and bottom margin of 16px ( 1em ) and a padding-left of 40px ( 2.5em ). The list items ( <li> elements) have no set defaults for spacing. The <dl> element has a top and bottom margin of 16px ( 1em ), but no padding set."_

So, you need to set the padding to 0 on your `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent stylesheet of the browser itself is applying that padding. If you want to get rid of it, you'll need to override it by setting:

```css
ul {
 /* All your other ul styling here... */
 padding-left: 0;
}
```